# Decimal formatting

Tags: c#, formatting, decimal

I have a decimal = 123456 and an integer = 5
I want to insert "." at the fifth position of my decimal from the right and get 1.23456
How can I do this with standard formatting functions (i. e. without dividing by power of 10 and only then formatting to add missing zeros)?
Thanks.

Comment: Wait, you want to go from 12345 to 1.2345 without doing math? Good luck with that...

Comment: Why don't you want to divide, if I may ask?

Comment: @AdrianCarneiro 1.2345 = 12345 * .0001

Comment: You're out of luck, the [number scaling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SpecifierTh) has a step of 1000, not 10000 or 100000. You'll have to divide.

Comment: Okay whats 12345 1.2345 or 0.12345?

Comment: You: _... only then formatting to add missing zeros_ Be aware that a number of type `decimal` (in .NET `System.Decimal`) can have trailing zeroes by itself, without special formatting. For example the product of `decimal x = 10000000m;` and `decimal y = 0.0001m;` will have a "scale" of 4 and hence show with four trailing zeroes with no special formatting (i.e. when just calling the parameterless `ToString()` method on the product).

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this?

```
decimal d = 10000000;
int n=4;

string s = d.ToString();
var result = s.Substring(0, s.Length - n) + "." + s.Substring(s.Length - n);
```

Comment: The first input is said to be a decimal, which raises the possibility of 10.00001, say. Which your code would turn to 10.0.0001

Comment: Have you heard of the instance method `Insert`, as in `s.Insert(i, ".")`?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen thanks alot. you made me learn something new. see my answer

Answer (score 1):

This was actually pretty interesting, at least, I think it was. I hope I didn't go stupidly overboard by throwing in negative numbers, or accounting for possible decimal input...

```
            decimal input;
            int offset;
            string working = input.ToString();
            int decIndex = working.IndexOf('.');
            if (offset > 0)
            {
                if (decIndex == -1)
                {
                    working.PadLeft(offset, '0');
                    working.Insert(working.Length - offset, ".");
                }
                else
                {
                    working.Remove(decIndex, 1);
                    decIndex -= offset;
                    while (decIndex < 0)
                    {
                        working.Insert(0, "0");
                        decIndex++;
                    }
                    working.Insert(decIndex, ".");
                }
            }
            else if (offset < 0)
            {
                if (decIndex == -1)
                {
                    decIndex = working.Length();
                }
                if (decIndex + offset > working.Length)
                {
                    working.PadRight(working.Length - offset, '0');
                }
                else
                {
                    working.Remove(decIndex, 0);
                    working.Insert(decIndex + offset, ".");
                }

            }
```

Comment: I applaud your effort sir. If nothing else you've proven that not dividing it by 100,000 and using ToString() is barking mad.

Comment: Yay! That's what I was going for.

Answer (score 0):

This is very ugly; What is the real value? 12345 or 1.2345? Why are you storing 12345 and then trying to *represent it* as a *different number*? Going off what you are trying to convey what you actually have is an fixed-point (encoded) value and you need to decode it first. i.e.

```
decimal fixedPoint = 12345
decimaldecoded = fixedPoint / (decimal)10000
decoded.ToString();
```

So in your code you should define that you have a

```
var fixedPoint = new FixedPointValue(12345, 5);
var realValue = fixedPoint.Decode();
```

If any other programmer looks at this, it is plainly easy why you have to format it in such a way.

Comment: Not often I makrk people down, but if that double hasn't gone very shortly I'm afraid I'll have to.

Comment: don't know why you are downvoting (granted typo on second edit)... he is storing 12345 in a decimal and expecting the string formatted version to represent a different  number! In this context, the value is fixed-point.

Comment: I hadn't yet. Will be now. He's using decimal, you are using double. Worse still he's almost certainly using decimal's or even ints to avoid the inherrent inaccuracies of floating point.

Comment: Does that negate my point? his decimal is storing one value and the string representation is of a completely different value? I'll edit to change to decimal, but I still think my point stands.

Comment: It's not brill idea admittedly, using a floating point type isn't even that clever though.

Comment: And I'm sorry, my "don't know why you are downvoting" was for the other vote. You commented just before my reply. :( Is my edited answer better now?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by [String.Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert.aspx)

```
decimal d = 100000000000;
string str = d.ToString();
int i = 5;
string str2 = str.Insert(str.Length - i, ".");
Console.WriteLine(str2);
Console.Read();
```